# How to make Angular proxy work with target, pathRewrite and POST method

Tags: angular, proxy

In my Angular 15 application, i want to redirect REST API requests to another port and path using Angular proxy.

For instance, for all the requests initialy sent to `http://localhost:4200/execution/api/v1/**`, i want to be redirected to `http://locahost:8090/api/v1/**`
I can make it work for GET requests, but not for POST or DELETE requests if i use both port redirection and path rewrite.

Here is the configuration i use in my `proxy.conf.json` to reproduce my problem :

```
{
    "/execution/api/v1/": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8090",
        "changeOrigin": false,
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "/execution": ""
        }
    }
}
```

I tried it with a POST request, but unfortunately, i got an error :

```
[webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Rewriting path from "/execution/api/v1/login" to "/api/v1/login"
[webpack-dev-server] [HPM] POST /execution/api/v1/login ~> http://localhost:8090
[webpack-dev-server] [connect-history-api-fallback] Not rewriting POST /api/v1/login/ because the method is not GET or HEAD.
```

How can i force the use of both the path rewrite and the port change for a POST method request ?